# cURL - Submit form not working as expected

Tags: bash, forms, shell, http, curl

I am writing a bash script that should simulate:

1. Typing into a search bar.
2. Submit its content.
3. Fetch the results page.

Given this basic example:

```
<input name="search"  type="TEXT">
<input name="submit" value="SUBMIT" type="SUBMIT" align="center">
```

I would use `curl -s -d "search=value%&submit=SUBMIT" <URL> > export.html` to submit this form and write the results into `export.html`.

Given the next form:

```
<form action="/search.asp" method="GET" name="mmssearch">
    <div class="search-group">
        <input class="search-input" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter search value here..." name="_search" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="form-submit" class="search-submit" type="submit" value="">
    </div>
</form>
```

I would use `curl -s -d "_search=value" <URL> > export.html`, however, the *form submission* outputs the same `html` into `export.html` as before the search, which means nothing has changed; it returns the homepage instead of the results page.

How would I go about submitting this form? Did I forget something?

**NB**: The target URL itself contains several forms (amongst mobile search bars, login forms & others) of which some are very if not to say exactly identical, hence, it would be reasonable telling the script to use this specific form.

Comment: The `-d, --data <data>` option of cUrl, without specifying a request method, will send a POST request by default. It would appear your form expects a GET. I would try: `curl -X GET -s -d "_search=value" <URL> > export.html` for starters and check the response html.

Comment: Hi @TravisClarke I tried that, but somehow I get the same results.

Comment: Without getting hands-on, the only other suggestion I have is to diagnose by running `curl` with either `-v` or `--trace -` and inspecting the header data. e.g. there may be a redirect that can be followed with `-L` ... among countless other possibilities.

Comment: Attach a trace file and I/we can attempt to assist you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally used he wrong link. The correct approach that worked for me in order to parse the results page via the `GET` method is:

```
curl -L '<URL>/search.asp?_search=value'
```

I needed the `-L` flag to follow the redirects, as thankfully stated by @TravisClarke. The `<URL>` in this case stands for Base URL. The `?` is pretty straight forward for experienced users; it passes a set of parameters to the target URL which in turn should output the desired result page.

There is no need for `-d` or `--data` flag as the parameters are passed directly through the link, as opposed to the `POST` method which should require `-d` and sometimes `--cookie` as well.